# Show module as hover item

Tags: module, jquery, module-display, css

I want to show a module when a page is loaded for the first time, but the module is in a hover type position so it's not actually on the page. Please see the image here for a better description:

[image]

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new module position to your template, close to the icon you want to use to trigger it. Add something like this to `JOOMLAROOT\templates\YOURTEMPLATE\index.php`:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('hiddenmodule')) : ?>
   <!-- Begin Hidden module-->
    <div id="hiddenModule" style="display:none">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="hiddenmodule" style="xhtml" />
     </div>
   <!-- End Hidden module-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

In `JOOMLAROOT\templates\YOURTEMPLATE\templateDetails.xml`:

```
<position>hiddenmodule</position>
```

Now style the div width id `hiddenmodule` using CSS, and use jQuery to trigger the `display` CSS value on hover.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is trigger a `mouseover` event using jQuery once the DOM is ready, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.element').trigger('mouseover');
});
```

I think the best thing to do first is to inspect the element in your browser, hover over the icon and see if any classes are add once hovered upon. If so, then you could do thing a little differently and add that same class on page load which might automatically show the box.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't load a module in that pop up. how can I do that?

Comment: It's rather hard to tell as I don't know how it currently gets loaded. Would you be able to provide a link to your site so I can get a better insight? Also, you want the box to appear when the page is loaded but for how long? And how do you hide it once it appears?

Comment: It's not on a site anywhere presently.

Comment: Ok so inspect the element and see what happens exactly when you hover over the icon. See if any classes or inline styling is added to the trigger or the box itself.